# Unity3D: Sprite renderer vs image renderer issues on canvas

Tags: user-interface, animation, unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet

I'm using sprites for an animated menu in my game.
I tried two methods:

1. Image Renderer: Replacing the image per frame with the sprite slice in the animation window
2. Sprite Renderer: Same method

I'm playing the sprite animation with no loop then rotating the transform on the z-axis.

The problem is that with the image the Screen Space overlay works well but the rotation of the transform causes the sprite to look glitchy and rough. With the sprite renderer however the Screen Space must be put to Camera and the sprites get placed between other assets in the world.

Example: http://postimg.org/image/436q9jvax/

Is there a way to either fix the roughness on the rotation using image or force the Camera Screen Space on top? My only concern with the 2nd option would be in relation to responsiveness for multiple devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest fix was to apply "**sorting layers**" to the canvas with the sprite renderers on to keep it on top.

I did however incorporate @beuzel's idea about separate cameras in the end and opted for 2D sprites with physics instead of a 3D rendered animation on canvas.

http://postimg.org/image/6qmtiirb9/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for making the good sample. A fix for the menu intersecting the world is using a seperate camera for the GUI layer. The rough animation might be a pixel perfect setting in the sprite rendering (just guessing).

I don't have enough reputation points to write this as a comment.